# swiper js не корректно выводит слайды

Tags: javascript, swiper

мне необходимо сделать слайдер на сайте, для этого я использовал библиотеку swiper js. В целом все получилось, но только почему то происходит не корректное отображение слайдов, то есть я хочу что бы показывалось 3 слайда, но вместо этого выводится 3 слайда - 2 отображаются нормально а 3 обрезан. подскажите пожалуйста что я сделал не так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<section class="reviews__python">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="reviews__python_wrapper ">
            <h2 class="reviews__python-title">Отзывы о курсе</h2>

            <div class="reviews__python-blocks-block-arrow-left">
                <img src="{% static 'image/course_python/reviews__python/arrow_left.png' %}" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="slide-content">
                <div class="reviews__python-blocks swiper-wrapper">
                    {% for review in reviews_dict %}
                        <div class=" reviews__python-blocks-block swiper-slide">
                            <div class="reviews__python-blocks-block-wrapper">
                                <div class="reviews__python-blocks-block-img">
                                    {% if review.review.user.profile_picture %}
                                        <img src="{{ review.review.user.profile_picture.url }}" alt="">
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                                <div class="reviews__python-blocks-block-info">
                                    <div class="reviews__python-blocks-block-info-title">
                                        {{ review.review.user.last_name }} {{ review.review.user.first_name }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="reviews__python-blocks-block-info-untitle">
                                        Курс {{ review.review.course.course_name }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="reviews__python-blocks-block-info-stars">
                                        <div class="reviews__block-autor-img-star_wrapper reviews__block-autor-img-star_wrapper-courses_python">

                                            {% for review_rating_bool in review.review_rating_bool %}
                                                {% if review_rating_bool %}
                                                    <div class="reviews__block-autor-img-star reviews__block-autor-img-star-active">
                                                        <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                {% else %}
                                                    <div class="reviews__block-autor-img-star">
                                                        <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                {% endif %}
                                            {% endfor %}

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="reviews__python-blocks-block-text">{{ review.review.text }}</div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            <div class="reviews__python-blocks-block-arrow-right">
                <img src="{% static 'image/course_python/reviews__python/arrow_right.png' %}" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

```css
    .reviews__python {
    margin-top: 170px
}
.container {
    padding: 0 75px;
    max-width: 1700px;
    margin: auto
}
.reviews__python_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    max: 1550px;
    height: 780px;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 72px
}
.reviews__python-title {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 64px;
    line-height: 78px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 35px;
    color: #FFFFFF
}
.reviews__python-blocks-block-arrow-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 345px;
    left: -32px;
    width: 65px;
    height: 55px;
    border-radius: 51.21px;
    background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.68);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .1s linear
}

.reviews__python-blocks-block-arrow-left:hover {
    background-color: rgba(115, 153, 236, 0.7)
}

.reviews__python-blocks-block-arrow-left img {
    position: relative;
    top: 13px;
    left: 16px
}

.reviews__python-blocks-block-arrow-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 345px;
    right: -32px;
    width: 65px;
    height: 55px;
    border-radius: 51.21px;
    background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.68);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .1s linear
}

.reviews__python-blocks-block-arrow-right:hover {
    background-color: rgba(115, 153, 236, 0.7)
}

.reviews__python-blocks-block-arrow-right img {
    position: relative;
    top: 13px;
    left: 16px
}
.slide-content {
    margin: 0 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.reviews__python-blocks {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 100px 50px 0 50px
}
.reviews__python-blocks-block {
    width: 450px;
    height: 440px;
    background-color: #85AEFF;
    border-radius: 60px
}
.slide-content {
    margin: 0 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.swiper-slide {
    width: 440px;
}
```

Comment: А ваш код покажите.

Comment: добавил html и css код

Comment: А инициализация слайдера? это на фулл разрешении?